# What did you say? In Corsica? Really?

Tags: riddle, wordplay

> A group of people
>
> In Corsica
>
> Carry out a chemistry measurement
>
> Which turns out to be highly acidic

What is that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> MOBILE PHONE

Title:

> Firstly, the title sounds like a conversation on a phone.

A group of people

> MOB

In Corsica

> ILE means ISLE in French thanks to the op

Carry out a chemistry measurement

> PH is a chemistry measurement

Which turns out to be highly acidic

> ONE, ph of one is highly acidic

Comment: Lbh unir gur frpbaq cneg nofbyhgryl anvyrq. Vg qbrfag arrq gb or n bar jbeq fbyhgvba. Svefg cneg pna or n qvssrerag jbeq?? Good Job though

Comment: Changed the answer, yeah I thought you were looking for one word...

Comment: Vyr vf n serapu jbeq  that is why Corsica

Comment: Oh I see, I looked up ile in google and french before and it directed me to a province, I thought ile meant province but now I learned something new today